# Decoded Timestamp is not the same date as original DateTime value

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf.js

We have a .NET application that defines a `DateTime` in the schema like so:

```
[ProtoMember(20)]public DateTime? Birthdate;
```

The application is able to serialize the data using `protobuf-net` and later upon deserialization the date is retrieved accurately as expected.

I am now trying to deserialize the same buffer in our node.js application using `protobuf.js`. I've defined that data point in the `.proto` file like so:

```
google.protobuf.Timestamp Birthdate = 20;
```

Upon decoding it the resulting Birthdate is not the same date as the original data. For example, when the date is originally 10/10/1976, the deserialized date is:

```
"Birthdate": {
    "seconds": "4948"
}
```

When creating a JavaScript `Date` from that (`new Date(4948 * 1000)`), the result is 1/1/1970. What is going wrong here?

Comment: 4948 seconds from the epoch is only ~1:22:28 so the date would rightfully be Jan 1, 1970. Maybe you forgot to include the days, month, and years?

Comment: Yah it seems something is missing, but there's nothing to miss right, because the data in the protocol buffer is correct, it is deserialized properly in the C# app, just not in the JS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to history. protobuf-net had support for `DateTime` a *long time* before there was a well-defined `Timestamp` in the shared libraries. So: it invented something that would allow round-trip between protobuf-net and itself. Many years later, along comes `Timestamp`, and ... put simply, it uses a different storage layout. The good news is: protobuf-net can talk that dialect, but *because we couldn't break existing code*, it is "opt in".

If you [use a `Timestamp` in a .proto](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/#g573b70906a7ea6ef66e8e5fdfb3f77f4), you can see that protobuf-net generates, for that .proto:

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(20, DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.WellKnown)]
public global::System.DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```

or more simply, to match your existing code:

```
[ProtoMember(20,DataFormat=DataFormat.WellKnown)]public DateTime? Birthdate;
```

With that in place - it should be using the same data layout tand you should get the same values. This is the recommended option if you need to exchange data between platforms. However, note that this is a change to your existing layout. If you need tips on migrating without breaking existing usage, let me know - it is possible (the short version would be "leave field 20 as the old style; add a new property that acts similarly and uses the new format - only serialize the new one, but allow the old one to deserialize").

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'll let you know if we could use more information in regards to a migration strategy.

Comment: It seems there may be a pattern with the current deserialization we could potentially investigate to avoid having to migrate. Can you see what it is doing with those dates in conversion? We've noticed if you take `seconds`, divide it by 2, add that as the number of days from epoch, we get the correct date. But this only works when no nanos are provided (time is 00:00).

Comment: Oh, I can tell you exactly what the format that protobuf-net uses by default. I can also say that I regret it - it seemed like a good idea at the time, but... Here you go: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/Tools/bcl.proto (look for DateTime). If you can move to the "well known" type, it would be my recommendation.